# Evaluating the matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, determinant, matrix-equations

I have a question that goes as follows:

Let $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{5}$ and $A=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos \alpha & \sin \alpha \\
    -\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \\    \end{bmatrix}
$
and let $B=A^4-A^3+A^2-A$

Then which of the following is true?
(i)B is singular (ii) B is non singular (iii) B is symmetric (iv) The determinant $|B| =1$

There may be multiple correct options.

Now here's what I did, I evaluated $A^2$ and $A^3$ and then it is pretty easy to conclude by induction that $$A^n = \begin{bmatrix}
    \cos n\alpha & \sin n\alpha \\
    -\sin n\alpha & \cos n\alpha \\    \end{bmatrix}$$

From this, I tried to find out $B$ by putting the values of $A^4, A^3, A^2, A$ and then applied the transformation formulae $\bigg($like $\sin C + \sin D=$ $2\sin\bigg( \frac{C+D}{2} \bigg)\cos\bigg( \frac{C-D}{2}$ $\bigg)$, $...$ etc$\bigg)$

By simplifying, and using the fact that $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{5}$ I got the matrix B as follows:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
    -4\cos \alpha \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} & 0 \\
   0 & -4\cos \alpha \sin \frac{\alpha}{2} \\    \end{bmatrix}$$

So, clearly, the matrix is symmetric, which makes (iii) true. But, how do I check whether the matrix is non-singular or not, and how do I check whether $|B|=1$? Using the manipulations that I performed, I seem to not be able to check those options, any help would be nice.

The answer is given as (ii), (iii), (iv) are true.

Comment: To check whether the matrix is non-singular, you can do many things, including computing its determinany.  Since you have an explicit $2\times2$ matrix, you can just compute its determinant like any other; and, since it's diagonal, it's especially easy because the determinant is just the product of the diagonal entries.  However, as you can see, the determinant of the matrix you've written is *not* $1$, so either the answer is wrong or there must be a mistake in your trigonometric identities somewhere.

Comment: Note that $B=A(A-I)(A^2+I)$ where $A$ is the rotation matrix by angle $\alpha$; if $B$ is singular, at least one of $A, A-I, A^2+I$ must be singular.

Comment: @LSpice There was a typo in the matrix that I initially wrote. But now I rectified it. Could you check now?

Comment: You don't need me to check; you can see for yourself that the determinant is not $1$.  But actually I don't get determinant $1$ either (although I get a different matrix from yours), so maybe there is some mistake with what you copied from the problem, or the answer.  (For example, if all the $-$s are $+$s, then you do get determinant $1$.)

Comment: No, right now the problem is exactly as stated in the book, so there may be some mistake in the question maybe? What matrix do you get?

Comment: My comments [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987657/evaluating-the-matrix-polynomial/3987689#comment8228691_3987657) [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3987657/evaluating-the-matrix-polynomial/3987689#comment8228715_3987657) are a bit stupid; I was misreading the problem.  I have (I think!) finally read the problem correctly, and posted an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3987689).

Comment: One observation which may be useful in future problems of this kind: If $M:=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i& 0\end{pmatrix}$, then one may represent the rotation matrix as the matrix exponential $A(\alpha)=\exp(i \alpha M)$. From this it immediately follows that $A(\alpha)^n=\exp(in\alpha M)=A(n\alpha)$, as you already discovered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to think of this is that you are essentially computing a geometric sum associated to $-A$.  As usual, we have that $(-A - 1)B = -A^5 + A = 1 + A$.  Since $-A - 1$ is non-singular (as you can compute by finding the determinant, by computing its eigenvalues, or just by explicitly writing down the inverse of a $2\times2$ matrix), we see that $B = -1$.  Sure enough, this is symmetric and has determinant $1$.

It may help in this case to think that we are essentially computing with complex numbers; the ring of complex numbers $\mathbb C$ embeds in the ring $\operatorname M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ of $2\times2$ real matrices by $a + b i \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$.  In particular, you are really computing a sum inside $\mathbb C$ involving $z = \cos(\alpha) + i\sin(\alpha) = e^{i\alpha}$.  In this context, the determinant on $\operatorname M_{2\times2}(\mathbb R)$ pulls back to the squared-norm on $\mathbb C$, in the sense that
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix} = a^2 + b^2 = \lvert a + b i\rvert^2
$$
for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$; and the transpose on $\operatorname M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ pulls back to complex conjugation on $\mathbb C$, in the sense that
$$
a + b i \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\overline{a + b i} = a - b i \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b & a \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}^{\mathsf T}
$$
for all $a, b \in \mathbb R$ (and remember that $\overline{e^{i\theta}}$ equals $e^{-i\theta}$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb R$); so asking whether the alternating sum of matrices is symmetric, respectively has determinant $1$, is the same as asking whether the corresponding alternating sum of complex numbers is real, respectively lies on the unit circle centred at the origin.  Finally, since $\mathbb C$ is a field, every non-$0$ matrix in the image of $\mathbb C$ is invertible (with the inverse of the image of $z = a + b i$ being the image of $z^{-1} = \frac a{a^2 + b^2} - \frac b{a^2 + b^2}i$ for all $(a, b) \in \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$); this is yet another way to see that $-A - I_2$ is non-singular.

Comment: Where do you get $A^5$ here?

Comment: From multiplying the $A^4$ that is a summand of $B$ by $-A$.  Or do you mean how do I get $A^5 = -1$?  That is from your inductive formula (or from the point of view of complex numbers).

Comment: Okay, I get what you meant there. But when you write $(-A-1)B=-A^5+1=1+A$, how are you reducing the matrix $A^5$ to a number? I think it can only be reduced if there is a determinant symbol there.

Comment: I mean by $1$ the identity matrix; you could write $(-A - I_2)B = -A^5 + A = I_2 + A$ if it made more sense.

Comment: How is $A^5 = -I_2$? Could you show that in your answers? I agree that the $\det (A^5)=1$ but how do you get that it is equal to the identity matrix?

Comment: You said that you understand that $A^n = \begin{pmatrix} \cos(n\alpha) & \sin(n\alpha) \\ -\sin(n\alpha) & \cos(n\alpha) \end{pmatrix}$.  Now just plug in $\alpha = \pi/5$ and $n = 5$.

Comment: okay yeah I was being kinda stupid there. So from there I get that $(-A-1)B= I_2+A$ Sure. Now how do you get that $det(B)= 1$?

Comment: Because $B = -I_2$.

Comment: but thats the part I do not get. How do you arrive  at the conclusion that $B=I_2$? I get that $A^5=-I_2$ But how do you get B = $-I_2$ from there?

Comment: Because $(-A - I_2)B = I_2 + A = (-A - I_2)(-I_2)$.  Now multiply both sides by $(-A - I_2)^{-1}$.  (This is where we use that $-A - I_2$ is non-singular.)

Comment: Ohh, thanks that helps :)